Is this interop p/invoke signature correct for the libc poll() function?
Is this the correct interop signature for calling the libc function poll()? I'm running dotnet8 on ubuntu 18.04 on an arm64 platform.
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PollFDStruct
        {
            public IntPtr fd;         // File descriptor to poll
            public short events;   // Requested events to watch
            public short revents;  // Returned events
        }

        [DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int poll([In, Out] PollFDStruct[] fds, ulong nfds, int timeout);

When I call poll with a SocketCAN socket handle it always times out. revents is always 0. If I read the socket after poll times out I do receive the data I'm expecting. I could just block on the read but I need a way to shut the thread down gracefully.
Anyone have any clues?

I set the read time out instead.
